# On an afterSubmit when we creating a copy of one inventory item (name with '-c') ,The original ID of item link should come in a field on a copy order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I tried this above, here I am getting a null value only from my previous record.
Kindly give some guidance to solve my questions.
thanks in advance.

```html
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(["N/url", "N/record", "N/runtime"], function (url, record, runtime) {
    function afterSubmit(context){
        var recordobj = context.newRecord;
        var prevItemrecord= context.oldRecord;
        var Itemname = recordobj.getValue({fieldId:'itemid'});
        var prevItemname = prevItemrecord.getValue({fieldId : 'itemid'});
        var Type=context.type;
        var checkbox=recordobj.getValue({fieldId:'custitem17'});
        if(Type== context.UserEventType.CREATE)      
        if((Itemname=prevItemname+'-c')&&(checkbox=true))
          record.submitFields({
              type: recordobj.type,
              id: recordobj.id,
              values:{custitem_item_link:prevItemname}
    });
}
    return{
        afterSubmit:afterSubmit
        } 
});
```

This is my code

Comment: A great deal of the code you have pasted does nothing. Unless a value is going to be used multiple times or you are trying to use variables to inline comment a value you do not gain anything in Javascript for pre-dereferencing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

On create there is no old record.

Since you are trying to update the same record as was just created you are better off having this in a beforeSubmit event script

`if((Itemname=prevItemname+'-c')&&(checkbox=true))` this is an error

`if((Itemname == prevItemname+'-c') && checkbox)` is more what you need

If you are trying to capture a copy operation you can set that up in the beforeLoad event that you use in the beforeSubmit event.

```js
function beforeLoad(ctx){
    if(ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.COPY){
        if(ctx.form){
            ctx.form.addField({
                id:'custpage_original_item',
                label:'Copied Item',
                type:ui.FieldType.SELECT,
                source:'item'
            }).updateDisplayType({
             displayType:ui.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
            }).defaultValue = ctx.request.parameters.id;

            // your naming makes me wonder if you are trying to link to the 
            // source item rather than just saving a reference to the source
            // item's name

            /*
             * Using the original item's name like below is closer to what you
             * posted but I think by the time the script runs the itemid field
             * has been cleared. 
  
             * ctx.form.addField({
             *     id:'custpage_original_item_name',
             *     label:'Copied Item Name',
             *     type:ui.FieldType.TEXT
             * }).updateDisplayType({
             *  displayType:ui.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
             * }).defaultValue = ctx.newRecord.getValue({fieldId:'itemid'});
  
             */
        }
    }
}

function beforeSubmit(ctx){
    if(ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.CREATE){
        const itemRec = ctx.newRecord;
        if(itemRec.getValue({fieldId:'custitem17'})){
            const sourceId = itemRec.getValue({fieldId:'custpage_original_item'})
            if(sourceId){
                itemRec.setValue({
                    fieldId:'custitem_item_link:prevItemname',
                    value:sourceId
                });
                /* or use a search function to look up the original item's name
                 * and then test the new item's name. 
                 */
            }
        }
    }
}
```